# UltraEdit FTP file size

Tags: ultraedit

In Ultraedit (Version 21.00.0.1030) I use the FTP client to connect to unix servers.  This client will show a listing of files in a folder, but the file sizes are in bytes.

I would like this to display using the ls -h (human readable) file sizes (MB, GB).  I don't readily see an option on how to do this and my searching has come back empty.

Comment: Better to ask on the ultraedit forums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FTP client in UltraEdit uses the FTP command **LIST** and not command **ls**.

There is no standard for FTP command **LIST**. Which switches are supported depends on FTP server.

There is the tab **Server** in **FTP Account Manager** dialog of UltraEdit with the option *LIST command filter*. Here it is possible to define the switches for **LIST** command.

Note: This edit field is disabled and therefore this option is not available if SFTP is selected as *Protocol* on tab **General**.

You can enter here `-h` and test if the FTP server recognizes it and returns the directory listings now with human readable file sizes. The FTP server to which I have established a connection ignored this switch while others worked. I could see that on tab **FTP Log** in **Output Window** after having enabled configuration setting *Show FTP log in output window* at **Advanced - Configuration - FTP**.

But I think, in general it is no good idea to use human readable file size listing. It could be that the FTP client does not know real file size in bytes of each file with human readable file size and therefore cannot check if a file is downloaded completely. I don't know if FTP client in UltraEdit or UE itself makes use of the file size information from listing on download of a file.